# How can I make a scope field specific to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a big form with a lot of dynamically generated input fields. These fields are generated by pushing an object to an array as follows:

```
$scope.addField = function() {
    $scope.step.fields.push({});
};
```

Now this works just fine. However I have one form in particular where the field is a child of another element named "step" that's also generated dynamically. The problem comes whenever I add a new Step form element in my form and then try to add another "field" as the "field" that I generate appears in every single "step" element that exists on the page and not only on the one I clicked on...

How can I prevent the field generated from showing up on every single "step" element?

Comment: Please include all code necessary to recreate the issue in the question itself. See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: You must show how you are adding the new element for us to advise you here. It *sounds like* the answer will be to move your DOM manipulation into the link function of a directive. But nobody can know without more code - make a JS fiddle or something

Comment: Ah ok, i couldn't get the JS fiddle to work correctly but you can at least see the code and the GUI https://jsfiddle.net/bgr0qdry/
The behaviour i'm getting is expected as i'm using two separate objects to define the elements and their child elements, i just don't know how to make the child object belong to the parent object.

So the problem is whenever i add a new form with the bottom button and **then** try to add a new row of fields with the upper button, the fields are added on every "step form"  that's generated and not just on the one i clicked. @WilliamB